# can't run apt --fix-broken install

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Can't use `apt` it say run `apt --fix-broken install` and after that throws an error. Tried installing libapt-pkg6.0 manually but can't fix the issue.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libapt-pkg6.0 : Depends: libzstd1 (>= 1.5.2) but 1.4.8+dfsg-3build1 is installed
                 Recommends: apt (>= 2.5.0) but 2.4.5 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Comment: qobgoli ukve tqvan did vardas te qianas

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but your message mixes *jammy* and *kinetic* package versions so what are you running?  Your issue is sources related.

Comment: Your operating system seems to be Ubuntu 22.04, however the version of libapt-pkg6.0 that you are trying to install manually is specific to Ubuntu 22.10. If your are indeed using Ubuntu 22.04 then you could install libapt-pkg6 by running `sudo apt install libapt-pkg6`